# make query in mysql to count member

Tags: mysql, sql

Write Mysql query with average age counting

Comment: This just looks like a dump of a question you have been asked to do with nothing more.  Have you tried anything yourself so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following

```
select
    ReportsTo,
    count(*) as Members,
    avg(age) as Average_Age
from yourTable
where ReportsTo is not null
group by
    ReportsTo
```

Comment: We don't  need null count. After run your query it will give us null count as well.

Comment: And Average will be round up like 23.50 then it will convert into 24 and if 23.40 then 22 like this

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite easy. This may work for you!

`SELECT ReportsTo, COUNT(Members) as Members, AVG(Age) as average 
FROM table 
GROUP BY ReportsTo 
ORDER BY ReportsTo`